# Woocommerce add free products with ACF Post Object field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to build a custom functionality in Woocommerce with Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) plugin.

I created some code already but it is not working properly.

I want to select (simple) products at a Woocommerce product with ACF post object field. That products must be added free into the Woocommerce cart when that product will be added to the cart. Also when I add two or more items the free products must be added together.

I got also some images how the situation should work.

*This is the ACF field setup.*

[image: ACF FIELD]

*For example: this is the product we give away.*

[image]

*This is the product we give away selected at a Woocommerce single product.*

[image]

This is my actual code:

```
add_action('woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'free_products' );

function free_products() { 
    if( ( is_cart() || is_checkout () ) {
        $free_product = get_field('gratis_producten'); // Incentive product we are giving away
        $cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $free_product );
        $free_products_in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $cart_id );

        if( $free_product ) {
            // Removing existing "free products" from the cart.
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $free_products_in_cart ); 
            // Adding to cart 40 free products 
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $free_product, 40 );
        }
    }
}
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.